# Installing python extension module : understanding skbuild+setuptools

Tags: python, c++, setuptools, pybind11, scikit-build

I am one of the devs of a (fairly large) C++ simulation tool. Disclaimer : I'm more of a physicist than a dev. I wrote Python bindings for that project using `pybind11`.

I managed to get the Python module to compile with `cmake`. I then managed to write a [`setup.py` file](https://gitlab.com/cytosim/cytosim/-/blob/pybind/setup.py) using `skbuild` that does compile the Python module :

```
python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

In `_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.9/cmake-build/lib/` (and in the tar archive `dist/cytosim-0.0.0.tar.gz`) there is indeed a compiled library : `cytosim.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

However, when I want to install the module :

```
pip3 install dist
```

I get an error :

```
gcc: error: src/py3/dist.c: No such file or directory
```

I am very confused because I do not have an directory called `py3` in `src`.

Any pointer ? Anything I'm doing wrong ? Thanks !

Comment: Seems like it is the installation from the _sdist_ that fails. Is it possible to install the wheel without issue?

Comment: The wheel installs fine (yeah thanks!) - but still I would like to install the sdist because of portability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command

```bash
pip3 install dist
```

tries (and fails) to install the [dist](https://pypi.org/project/dist/) package from the pypi repository.

Maybe try

```
pip3 install dist/cytosim-0.0.0.tar.gz
```

instead.

Comment: Yes, that seems spot on. Here is the `setup.py` of `dist` on _PyPI_: https://inspector.pypi.io/project/dist/1.0.3/packages/5c/2f/76760a4bf4fe7423c387eca4a8a8363fc74ee30cadb1a20ee8e38bc8a69f/dist-1.0.3.zip/dist-1.0.3%2Fsetup.py